# Gradient colour on UV mapping

Tags: uv

I watched a [youtube tutorial on making a clover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Njgtws6wLlM) and I want to make the same by myself. From the video, it seems that clover is shaded using UV map

[image]

and then some gradient texture in the "Texture Properties" tab instead of shading nodes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The result is

[image]

However, I encountered some problems below:
1) The video is too fast to follow even though it is played at 0.25 speed
2) I am using Blender 2.82 but it seems that the Blender version in the tutorial is 2.79 or earlier.

Can somebody teach me how it can be done in Blender 2.8. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's this kind of node chain: *Texture Coordinate > Mapping > Gradient > ColorRamp > Diffuse > Output*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you moonboots. I get a very close image! Thanks a lot!